# Proof of let $\gamma(t)$ be a regular curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then find its curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Andrew Pressley's elementary differential geometry, this is proposition 2.1.2 in that book, I don't understand how it got the equation (2.3) in the proof.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The author is looking to compute

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\frac{d \gamma}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\right)$$ which is the derivative of a ratio of maps. And as you know

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right) = \frac{\frac{df}{dt}g - \frac{dg}{dt}f}{\left(\frac{dg}{dt}\right)^2}.$$

This is exactly what is applied here with $f=\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$ and $g=\frac{ds}{dt}$.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just found I don't understand why in the second line $\dot{\gamma}=\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}$, if s is reparametrization of t, then shouldn't be $\gamma^{'}(s(t))=\gamma(t)$, so $\frac{d \gamma}{dt}=\frac{d \gamma^{'}}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}$? And also why in 2.3, it get $\kappa=||d^2\gamma/ds^2 ||$, shouldn't be $\kappa=||d^2\gamma/dt^2 ||$? And why $\kappa=||d^2\gamma/dt^2 ||$=$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\frac{d \gamma}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\right)$?

Comment: No it is $\kappa=\lVert d^2\gamma/dt^2 \rVert$ by definition as only the curvilinear abscissa is an intrinsic parameter. Also $d^2\gamma / dt^2 = d/dt\left( d \gamma/dt\right)$.

Comment: Also why it change ds to dt in $\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\frac{d \gamma}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\right)$ =$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\frac{d \gamma}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\right)/ds/dt$?

Comment: This is an application of the chain rule for the derivatives.

Comment: what curvilinear abscissa is an intrinsic parameter means?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll Too many questions! I suggest that you revisit your courses for (1) calculus and derivatives and (2) definitions of curvilinear absciss, curvature, and so on. And then proceed step by step using my response.

Comment: Basically the content in your answer is the only thing I already understood before asking the question, thanks anyway.

Comment: You said that what you don't understand is line (2.3).... and this is exactly what I answered. $\kappa = d^2 \gamma / ds^2$ is just a definition.

Comment: By definition $\kappa = d^2 \gamma / dt^2$, I think.

Comment: $\kappa = d^2 \gamma / dt^2$ is wrong. This is why I suggested that you have to go back to your course.

Comment: *unit-speed curve with parameter t* is exactly the curvilinear absciss. In the proposition 2.1.2 of your question, nowhere it is stated that $t$ is unit-speed. Even more $s$ **is stated to be the unit speed** below in the first sentence of the proof. Hence $\kappa = d^2 \gamma / ds^2$.

Comment: The definition in the book said if $\gamma$ is a unit-speed curve with parameter t, its curvature $\kappa(t)$ at the point $\gamma(t)$ is defined to be $||\ddot{\gamma}(t)||$, and if $\gamma$ is only regular, then it has a unit-speed parametrization $\hat{\gamma}$, then its curvature to be that of $\hat{\gamma}$. So in 2.1.2 $\gamma$ is only regular, then by definiton shouldn't first transfer $\gamma$ to $\hat{\gamma}$, then to calculate $||\ddot{\hat{\gamma}}(s)||$, but in 2.1.2, it calculates $||\ddot{\gamma}(s)||$ instead.

Comment: Sorry... I give up.

Comment: After a while I realized why my understanding about the definition was wrong, thank you so much for pointing out it!!!! (No need to reply, I am welcome to replies, just worried that you may not feel comfortable to reply, sorry for the troubles)